# Android Studio - Build Failed after import project with facebook sdk and jsoup 1.7.2 sources.jar

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, jsoup, libs

I just moved from Eclipse to Android Studio. In Eclipse I had a project running with facebook and jsoup libraries properly configured and working.
But when I imported the project into Android Studio I got build failed. I searched a lot here but I couldn't find a solution. Here is what I got as structure today:

```
Workspace \TripFinder (package name)
```

Inside TripFinder: 
(4 four folders)

```
.gradle
.idea
facebookSDK
gradle
tripFinder
```

(7 seven files)

```
build.gradle
gradlew
gradlew.bat
import-summary
local.properties
settings.gradle
TripFinder.iml
```

What I think is weird is that inside tripFinder folder besides build and src folder I got build.gradle and tripFinder.iml files (It seems to me redundant). I have the same structure inside Facebook Folder.

```
In Files > Project Structures... I have two modules> Facebook and TripFinder modules.
```

Inside Facebook dependencies: com.android.tools.idea.structure.ModuleDependenciesTableItem@668baf3
inside tripFinder dependencies i put:

```
- admob (stopped giving me errors as was before)
- facebookSDK
- jsoup 1.7.2.jar
- jsoup 1.7.2-sources.jar
- jsoup 1.7.2-javadoc.jar
```

But When I try to build I got this  2 errors:

```
: duplicate files during packaging of APK C:\Users\Tiago\Documents\Android\Workspace_appsTMA\TripFinder\tripFinder\build\apk\tripFinder-debug-unaligned.apk
```

and

```
Execution failed for task ':tripFinder:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK org/jsoup/nodes/entities-base.properties
    File 1: C:\Users\Tiago\Documents\Android\Workspace_appsTMA\TripFinder\tripFinder\src\main\libs\jsoup-1.7.2-sources.jar
    File 2: C:\Users\Tiago\Documents\Android\Workspace_appsTMA\TripFinder\tripFinder\src\main\libs\jsoup-1.7.2-sources.jar
```

Please, if the solution is to write something into build.gradle file, tell me which one should I edit because I got three build.gradle files.
One at the root folder (tripfinder), another one inside facebook folder and another one inside tripFinder folder (the nested folder in the root). Thank you guys.

If you need anything else, please, just ask I'll be help to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Duplicate files copied in APK org/jsoup/nodes/entities-base.properties

Both `jsoup 1.7.2.jar` and `jsoup 1.7.2-sources.jar` contain `org/jsoup/nodes/entities-base.properties`, try removing `jsoup 1.7.2-sources.jar` from your build path and rebuild again.

Comment: Thank you. I just removed ...sources.jar and it built! I didn't realized that since Eclipse was ok with it...

Answer (score 0):

The doc does not show? In that case you can try removing **jsoup 1.7.2-sources.jar**, and enter the `Jsoup.connect` object, and android studio will notify you to download Java 5.0. Then the doc can show.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'org/jsoup/nodes/entities-full.xml'
    exclude 'org/jsoup/nodes/entities-full.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.jsoup/jsoup/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.jsoup/jsoup/pom.properties'
    exclude 'org/jsoup/nodes/entities-base.properties'
    exclude 'org/jsoup/nodes/entities-base.xml'
}
```

but Jsoup will error, although can compile finish. so don't do this.